Google Chrome ignores standard (grayscale) antialiasing font-rendering setting
Running Ubuntu 24.04.1, I installed official Google Chrome using their .deb package.
I used the Gnome Tweaks app to set the antialiasing to Grayscale:

This works on Ubuntu apps:

But Google Chrome still uses Subpixel method for antialiasing.

Interestingly, it works when I disable antialiasing!

for some reason, the gnome-tweaks aliasing setting gets overridden by /etc/fonts/conf.d/10-sub-pixel-rgb.conf
swapping value "rgb" to "grayscale" inside the file fixes the problem
